# What is the name of Django application's default server(Built in server)?

Tags: python, django, server, wsgi

I am writing a synopsis for one of the Academic Django project, which is going to run on localhost(no deployment). Now, in synopsis I want to mention server name. I know Django has built in server, what is the name of that server? can anyone sort it out? Thank you.

Comment: You can call it the "django development server"